# Gradle 5.0: The domain object 'test' (Test) for this provider is no longer present in its container

Tags: java, gradle

I recently wanted to see if our existing, working gradle scripts that run under 4.10.2 work on the new Gradle 5.0 release. I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not create task ':jacocoTestReport'.
   > The domain object 'test' (Test) for this provider is no longer present in its container.
```

I don't believe the issue actually has anything to do with jacoco. I can remove jacoco and I still get the error in seemingly random places. The error message doesn't make sense to me. Any help would be appreciated. Just a pointer would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass `--stacktrace` on command line to get a line number if that helps

Comment: You know I forgot about that because it usually doesn't help. I think it does have something to do with jacocoplugin:

Comment: It appears that we are removing the 'test' task from the projects and this upsets jacocoplugin. This is more of an issue particular to us. Thanks for the suggestion.